# SAP SuccessFactors Odata API, effective Date filter

Tags: odata, sap-successfactors

I'm trying to get data in between the dates 2020-04-01 and 2021-03-31.
I tried the query posted below but I got data from earlier than 2020-04-01.

Is my query wrong?

```
/odata/v2/EmpJob?$format=json&fromDate=2020-04-01&toDate=2021-03-31
```

I changed entities, queries, and so on. I expect to get data exactly between 2020-04-01 and 2021-03-31.

Answer (score 0):

One would think that it would indeed be as simple as that. However:
https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/2920680

It seems that the 2 conditions are seen separately instead of a combined filter.

> **Cause** This is expected behavior. In short: it is not possible to combine two 'lastModifiedDateTime' filters to represent a time
> interval. Even if it seems to make sense semantically, the API will
> not interpret it as a range. The key idea to understand this is that
> the 'lastModifiedDateTime' filter looks at all the effective dated
> records of an employee as one object of analysis.
>
> Although the query's semantic structure suggests the following logic:
>
> ***IF ANY of the employee's records has 'lastModifiedDateTim' greater than provided date AND lesser than the other provided date, return
> true.***
>
> The actual logic is as below:
>
> ***IF ANY of the employee's records has 'lastModifiedDateTime' greater than provided date AND ANY of the employee's records has
> 'lastModifiedDateTime' lesser than the other provided date, return
> true.***
>
> So, for all the records related to a specific user, it can find one
> whose LMD>2020-04-21T07:38:00Z and it can find another one whose
> LMD<2020-04-21T08:38:00Z.
>
> Which record(s) are returned will be determined by the 'asOfDate' or
> 'fromDate' and 'toDate' parameters you are passing to the query. If
> none of there parameters are being passed (as is the case for the
> query used as example in this KBA), the query implicitly passes
> 'asOfDate'=today and the employee's current active record is returned.
> See Effective Dating Query in OData for more information.